# Howto send PUT request without content and Content-Length header with Apache http client?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, content-length

I'd like to test (via automated test) how server (and all proxies in-the-middle) responds to a PUT request **without** body and `Content-Length` header.

Similar to what curl does

```
curl -XPUT http://example.com
```

**with Apache HTTP client** (4.5.13)

But it looks like it always adds `Content-Length` header if I specify no body.
Is there any way to do that with Apache HTTP client?

Already tried (no luck)

```
final HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);
request.removeHeaders("Content-Length");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a request interceptor to modify requests generated by the standard protocol processor

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .addInterceptorLast((HttpRequestInterceptor) (request, context) ->
                request.removeHeaders(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH))
        .build();
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut("http://httpbin.org/put");
httpClient.execute(httpPut, response -> {
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
    return null;
});
```